# MS access and SQL SERVER last

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

I have a query in MS Access where one of my criteria is LAST for a particular field. I'm trying to replicate it to a VIEW however, there is no option for that. What is the equivalent?

Comment: There isn't a LAST in sql server. But there are ways to accomplish what you are trying to do. top 1 order by x is one way. Perhaps you can share your query and we can help you find a solution.

Comment: Sort in descending order and select the first record.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a sub-query like this:

```
SELECT ID, Name,
  (SELECT TOP 1 FieldName FROM SubTable
   WHERE MainTable.SubTableID = SubTable.ID
   ORDER BY DateEntered DESC) AS LastSimulation
FROM MainTable
```

The WHERE clause is optional if you need to filter records in SubTable by a value in MainTable